# Methods for creating good admin documentation?

Tags: administration, documentation

I want to document any change I do to my ubuntu system. I want to do this in a way that if I had to pass this system to another administrator, it would be easy and logical for him to access this documentation and use it for any purpose. The main reason that  I want to do this is so I can look back and see exaclly what's done to solve a problem and so on.

What would be the best way to do this? I am thinking placement of the documentation files and methods of creating and viewing them easily.

Another reason I want to learn good documentation is that one of the LPIC-1 books says this is very importaint, but does not elaborate much on the subject.

Hope this question was'nt to distro independent or unclear.

**Update:** (have made some ideas and more thoughts on the subject)

I've got a Dell Inspiron 1564 with BCM4312 wireless card on which the Broadcom Sta/wl driver caused kernel panic. I do not remember everything I tried to fix it, and I do not remember how exaclly I fixed the problem. I also have problems with my new driver, and I miss not having documented this locally.

What I want, is a folder which contains both documentation on what has been done, what is installed on the system and also perhaps HOWTOs for new desktop users. I want a pager, like `less` to display these files, and I want to use a good location to store them. (usr/share/doc?) This is in addition to commenting in config files and scripts.

I altso want to create a function that lists all the documentation. I think I need to write a script, with options to create, print and list my doc files. Am I on the right track at all here?

I reckon it is not actually necessary to write a script for this, but I think it might be good learning, anyways. I am thinking something simple like this:

- docfile list `#To list all doc files and howto files.`
- docfile -n  or filename.howto `#Create new/edit file doc tile`
- docfile  `#View file in pager like less`

Yeah, I've got some time on my hands at the moment.. :)

**To cut the question to the bone:** I want a simple and elegant way to create and print documentation locally. Is the suggestion above (a script) a reasonable way to solve this? And where should I place these files? Is /usr/source/doc/docfiles the place to save them?

Comment: @Rinzwind: Please add a comment if this was the kind of you were talking about! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a script.

We have a post installation script for when we need to install a new server. After the basic Ubuntu server is installed we do a semi-unattended installation of apache, mysql and some other software. Then we extract an image with our software and settings for both apache (ie. site-enabled) and mysql (ie. my.cnf).

The fun part of Linux is that anything is a file so this script also has lots of "sed" statements that alter settings files from command line. Think along the lines of performance tweaks, cron jobs in `/etc/crontab`, our own log files.

Comments above the commands make sure anyone should be able to understand what is happening.

Having these things on paper only works in theory but after a while it is useless since  people forget to update changes they made ... Having them in a script will have everyone updating this script (since it makes their work easier).

Comment: I am not sure you understood my question, and that I understand your answer. I will update my question for more details. Thanks!